# Knockout OptionsAfterRender not running

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to run some code after the optionsAfterRender event, but my function, createPortfolioMultiselect, is not being called and there are no errors.

```
<select id="PortfolioSelector" data-bind="options: listEntities, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsAfterRender: createPortfolioMultiselect, value: selectedPortfolio, event: { change: portfolioChanged }"></select>

mViewModel = {
                selectedPeriod: ko.observable(),
                listPeriods: ko.observableArray(),
                selectedPortfolio: ko.observable(),
                selectedPortfolioText: ko.observable(),
                listEntities: ko.observableArray(),
                periodChanged: function (pContext) {
                    // do some work
                },
                portfolioChanged: function () {
                    // do some work
                },
                createPortfolioMultiselect: function (option, item) {
                    // do some work here
                },
                LastRunReports: ko.observableArray()
            };
```

Comment: It *will* get called when it's not empty. See http://jsfiddle.net/2vywqm22/

Comment: Thanks for reply haim770, but in my case I am dynamically changing the listEntities population based on the selection of a different drop down. And in this case it does not trigger the event. So perhaps this event only runs the first time?

Comment: @DavidChoi perhaps you could post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Ok its because I'm using an older version of knockout, 2.2.1. I think this feature only came out 2.3. Sorry guys thanks.

Comment: humm working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2vywqm22/2/. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was using an older version of knockout, 2.2.1, that does not support this feature. User error.